# VB.NET - oledbcommand query is showing syntax error

Tags: vb.net, oledbcommand

I am getting syntax error in the below insert query at line
 cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

I have checked the datatypes of the parameters and the values supplied. They are correct.

the variables with suffix 'CB' stands for Combobox. I initially used
itemCB.selectedItem.toString. But now changed to itemCB.text. But anyway both are not working.

Couldnt find out the syntax error for very long time.
Could someone pls help me.

```
Dim cmdText As String
            cmdText = "insert into tblSales(salesDate,item,type,container,quantity,amount,custId,custName,custPhNo,custPlace,custEmail,remarks) values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"

            Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand
            cmd.CommandText = cmdText
            cmd.Connection = MainForm.con

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@salesDate", salesDate.Value.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"))
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@item", itemCB.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@type", typeCB.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@container", containerCB.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@quantity", CInt(qty.Text))
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@amount", CInt(amount.Text))
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@custId", CInt(custId.Text))
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@custName", custName.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@custPhNo", custPhNo.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@custPlace", custPlace.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@custEmail", custEmail.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@remarks", remarks.Text)
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Answer (score 0):

Which database are you using?, the syntax of the Insert statement feels strange to me. I would expect something in the line of:

```
  cmdText = "insert into tblSales(salesDate,item,type,container,quantity,amount,custId,custName,custPhNo,custPlace,custEmail,remarks) values(@salesDate,@item,@type,@container, @quantity,@amount,@custId,@custName,@custPhNo,@custPlace,@custEmail,@remarks)"
```

Marking in which position is going every parameter.

Comment: I use MSAccess database

Answer (score 0):

I am using MS Access as my back end database, in which 'Container' is a keyword. As my table column, was named as container, it raised this error.

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@container", containerCB.Text) ==> the error was here.

Now I changed the column name to 'containerType'

Syntax error got resolved